# Default Arguments in Python for Import

Tags: python

I have a small module written as:

Contents of psychometrics.py

```
def prob3pl(theta, D = 1.7, a, b, c): 
    result = c + (1 - c) / (1 + np.exp(-D * a * (theta - b)))
    return(result)

def gpcm(theta, d, score, a, D=1.7):
    Da = D * a
    result = np.exp(np.sum(Da * (theta - d[0:score]))) / np.sum(np.exp(np.cumsum(Da * (theta - d))))
    return(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gpcm(theta, d, score, a, D=1.7)
    prob3pl(theta, D = 1.7, a, b, c)
```

Now using the python interpret I do the following:

```
import psychometrics as py
import numpy as np
py.prob3pl(0, a = 1, b= 0, c=0)
```

However, when running this yields

```
>>> py.prob3pl(0,a=1,b=0,c=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: prob3pl() missing 1 required positional argument: 'D'
```

When I copy and paste the function into the interpreter it runs using the default value of `D = 1` but when importing that isn't happening.

What error am I making such that the default value for D is not recognized when I import the module?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has syntax error -

```
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

Therefore, kindly change function prob3pl() as

```
def prob3pl(theta, a, b, c, D = 1.7): 
    result = c + (1 - c) / (1 + np.exp(-D * a * (theta - b)))
    return(result)
```

Reason - In python function declaration, there should not be any non-default argument after any default argument. as D=1.7 here

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I made this exact change to the contents of psychometrics.py as suggested, but the same error occurs when running in the intepreter.

Comment: With apologies, the suggestion above does indeed work. Much appreciated

Comment: @user350540, i'm glad it helped. could you mark the answer as accpeted?